# How do I connect to a kerberos authenticated REST service in Python on Windows

Tags: python, windows, python-requests, kerberos

I am trying to create a very simple Python script to download the contents of an internal service at my company that sits within our firewall and authenticates using kerberos.

When I installed the requests_kerberos module I first edited the `import kerberos` in it to use `import kerberos_sspi as kerberos` instead after having installed the `kerberos_sspi` module.

Thus I have the following Python script

```
import requests
from requests_kerberos import HTTPKerberosAuth

response = requests.get('http://service.internaldomain',auth=HTTPKerberosAuth())

print response
```

While trying to process the 401 it crashes out with the error.

```
error: (-2146893053, 'InitializeSecurityContext', 'The specified target is unknown or unreachable')
```

While looking into seeing if I could do this with `curl` instead I ran `kinit` and noticed that it asked me for the password to authorisation with the following prompt:

```
Password for username@additionalInternalDomain.internaldomain
```

Thus I wondered if this might be what is causing the issue.

Comment: It looks like this is caused by the service I am connecting to not properly / at all supporting kerberos though since SSO magically works without a user prompt for IE and Chrome I am doubtful of this.

Comment: In the end I have given up and used basic auth instead with a dummy account for the service whose password it does not matter if it became widely known.

Comment: have you got solution for it ??

Comment: Hi Qasim - As noted above it turns out my internal service was poorly documented and did not support kerberos so I used basic auth instead with a dummy account.

Comment: Please make your last comment into an answer - its Ok to do this and it helps signpost it better for Google searchers.

Comment: While I used a Basic Auth and it solved my problem, I do not believe it was the true answer. One day someone may figure out what this actually is and leave a true answer.

Comment: @JamesRobinson The python community may have moved on to open ID et al. I would be surprised if anyone spends the time to write the (proper) library for Kerberos on Windows. Only the large corporates are still stuck with Kerberos on Windows. There is always a lag before the large organisations get to new techologies.

Comment: By the way.. I have left below an answer that actually works.

Answer (score 5):

I have tried multiple libraries on python and failed when trying to authenticate from a windows machine.There is no easy way. The Kerberos libraries mainly work on Linux. The workarounds for Windows do not work. So what can be the solution to this.
Well... be a Roman while in Rome. Try the windows native libraries from Python.

```
 import sys
 import clr
 from System.Net.Http import *
 myClienthandler = HttpClientHandler()
 myClienthandler.UseDefaultCredentials = True
 myClient = HttpClient(myClienthandler)
 x = myClient.GetStringAsync("putyourURLwithinthequoteshere")
 myresult = x.Result
 print(myresult)
```

Note that the this python script will have to run by the user who has access to the URL you are trying to access. By setting `UseDefaultCredentials` property  as `True`, you are passing the Kerberos tickets for the logged in user.

Comment: Thank you, sadly I can't confirm it works on the server I was dealing with as I no longer work there. But you are definitely correct about the large corporates.

Comment: I tried the above mentioned code with a kerberos authenticated webapi and I can confirm this works. It would be helpful for people who come here if you mark this as the answer.

Comment: Just to add, you need to install the `pythonnet` library for this snippet to work.

Comment: I needed to add `clr.AddReference("System.Net.Http")` for this to work.

Answer (score 1):

The server is giving you a 401 challenge - and the client (usually a browser or even curl) provides the credentials in a subsequent call. If you are already logged in at your domain - try forcing a pre-emptive hop, i.e. you’d carry your Kerberos ticket with your call and the server will not give you a 401 challenge:

`kerberos_auth = HTTPKerberosAuth(force_preemptive=True)
r = requests.get("http://myhost/DXAPIGraphQL/api/graphql", auth=kerberos_auth)`

If the above doesn't help look into the:
principal and hostname_override arguments of the HTTPKerberosAuth class.

Comment: Sadly I no longer work at that company so I can't try it out.

Answer (score 0):

I had to connecto to a REST API who's in a keberized environment just now.

After some reading, i came to this (and it worked):

```py
    tk = 'long_kerberos_token'
    headers = {'Authorization': 'Negotiate' + tk}
    r = requests.get(url=PING_URL, headers=headers)
```